# How to get current time+n months in java?

Tags: java

I have searched a lot on internet about how to get current time in Java but what I am looking for is how to get current time + n months?

Comment: Be careful though, be sure to check your use case. Adding a month, what does this mean? What should happen 31st of January when you add a month? Should you get 28th of Feb (and in some years 29th)? (probably yes). What is your use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, numberofMonths);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use `Java 8`, use [`LocalDate.plusMonths()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths-long-)

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
localDate.plusMonths(numberOfMonths);
```